# Azure WorkerRole running on local dev-fabric, but not on azure

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

My WorkerRole seems to just fine locally. However, it wont run on Azure itself - the role just keeps coming up as 'Busy' and never reaches the ready/running stage.

The associated web role works perfectly.

Could this just be a minor config bug or?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this in the end?

Answer (score 0):

See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazure/thread/6c739db9-4f6a-4203-bbec-eba70733ec16.

Comment: I've gone through and checked out that thread (and the linked thread at the bottom).

I've manage to get Intellitrace working, and I'm getting a the following error (it is the first of a list, so i assume it's having knock-on effects?):

Call Stack Location
WaWorkerHost.exe!Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Hosts.Worker.Loader.DebuggerAttach()

IntelliTrace time contect:
: Thrown: "No handle of the given name exists." (SystemThreading.WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException).

I'm at a loose end as to what is actually causing this?

Comment: In addition, I'm getting a System.IO.FileNotFoundException for the associated web role, even though the web role runs fine in the cloud and it's 'copy local' attribute IS set to true.